# POST Values are not recognized

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework, post

I'm using the Zend Framework and jQuery.

I'm calling a JavaScript function, which sends POST-Data to a PHP scripts and waits for an answer.

Everything worked fine this morning. I'm using Debian.
The values are send via the header, Firebug gives me the following Output:

```
Parameterapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
endDatum    
funktionsId 1
mitgliederId    10368
startDatum  31.03.2013
Quelle
mitgliederId=10368&funktionsId=1&startDatum=31.03.2013&endDatum=
```

But neither the `$_POST` Variable or the Zend Framework Method `$this->getRequest()->getParams();` gives me anything.

Any idea what's wrong? 
Maybe something is wrong with my php.ini Settings?
What settings can I change to modify the header-output?

---

Solved it: the problem was the subdomain i set up for the page. The AJAX-Reuquest weren't called correctly

Comment: Just a suggestion: Get rid of the german variable names. Code should be in english. It's usually easier to understand for others and often the english words are shorter, too. (Oh, and I'm german myself - but despise any German variable names etc. anyway.)

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with the fact you're using jQuery, it seems like the request is being sent correctly.

Comment: yeah, that's the problem. Everything seems finde, but var_dump($_POST) gives me back array(0){} - so something has to be wrong ;)

Comment: Maybe you can get more information if you `var_dump($_SERVER)`...

Comment: Maybe a little more detail might help. Context for the request might be helpful. Is it possible a new request is somehow being started at an inappropriate time?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for getting post values...

```
$this->getRequest()->getPost();
```

or for individual form elements

```
$this->getRequest()->getParams('elementName');
```